# ASP.net Jquery cant find prettyPhoto() function

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Iv been stuck on this for a little bit so figured i would ask someone else smarter :) I have a .NET website that I am trying to use the prettyPhoto Jquery plug in. I have included the Jquery main library and the PrettyPhoto.js file in the master page. I have been having similar problems with other Jquery plugins too where I cant find the function in the library, Whats the best way to avoid these problems? I am supposed to keep all the Jquery files in the master page right? and the CSS links as well? I have posted the code on my page, please give an example by code how to get the prettyPhoto() function. Thanks in advance!!

```
  <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Project.Master"    
  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Portfolio.aspx.cs" Inherits="Project.Portfolio" %>
  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">

 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function () {
     debugger;
       //This throws error Object doesn't support property or method 'prettyPhoto'
       $("ul.gallery").prettyPhoto();
     });
</script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Stylesheets/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css"     
  media="screen" title="prettyPhoto main stylesheet" charset="utf-8" />
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">

  ul li { display: inline; }

  </style>

  </asp:Content>
 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

 <div id="main">
 <h2>Gallery</h2>
        <ul id="picGallery" class="gallery">
            <li><a href="../images/Portfolio/fullscreen/2krew.jpg"    
 rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="You can add caption to pictures. You can add    
 caption to pictures. You can add caption to pictures."><img src="../images/thumbnails
 /2Krewtn.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Red round shape" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="../images/Portfolio/fullscreen/anaura" 
 rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="You can add caption to pictures. You can add 
 caption to pictures. You can add caption to pictures."><img src="../images/thumbnails
 /anauratn.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Red round shape" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="../images/Portfolio/fullscreen/closed.jpg" 
 rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]" title="You can add caption to pictures. You can add 
 caption to pictures. You can add caption to pictures."><img src="../images/thumbnails
 /Closedtn.jpg" width="200" height="200" alt="Red round shape" /></a></li>

        </ul>

 </div>

 </asp:Content>
```

Comment: I'd start with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see if you get any exceptions that might prevent your script from running correctly (and if your script file actually is loaded)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the correct approach, but to solve this issue with jquery and master pages firing the jquery plug in with standart javascript code, rather then the jQuery document.ready:

On the bottom of my page I added this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    StartJqeryPlugin();

    function StartJqeryPlugin() {

        window.setTimeout(function () {
        $("ul.gallery").prettyPhoto();
        });
        }, 250);
    }
```